# How to override td title attribute in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I would like to override the td property title that jqgrid generates with a value from a hidden column from the colmodel.  I can see how to turn it off completely but not how to change it.

Answer (score 2):

The best way for setting of custom tooltips on the cells of some column is usage of `cellattr` in the definition of the column in `colModel`. The `cellattr` callback allows to define **any** attribute which will be assigned to `<td>` elements in the corresponding column. Typically one uses the callback to set `style`, `class`, `title`, `data-someName`, ... attributes. In the simplest form the function can be defined as

```js
cellattr: function () { return ' title="the tooltip text"'; }
```

The function `cellattr` should return the string in the form `attributeName=AttributeValue`. Some old versions of jqGrid appended the resulting string directly to `<td>` without the space required mostly between attributes. The last version of jqGrid don't have such problem. Nevertheless I place starting space at the beginning of the returned string to make the code which works in all versions of jqGrid.

The callback `cellattr` will be called with 5 arguments and the value of `this` will be initialized to DOM of the grid (the main table element):

```js
cellattr: function(rowId, cellValue, rawObject, cm, rdata) {
    ...
}
```

In the most cases `rawObject` (3-d parameter) is the parameter which is the mostly interesting. It represent the input data for the row of the grid. The only problem that the format of the parameters depends on the format of input data and from the usage of `loadonce` parameter (in case of loading the data from the server per Ajax). [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16615231/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8022860/315935) shows how you can use the option in case of different format of input data.